# How to cache OData feed?

Tags: javascript, caching, odata

I'm developing OData client based on web technologies like HTML5, CSS and JavaScript.

What I want to do is to cache OData feed which is the latest version (V3) in an easy way.

I could implement the feature by using local or session storage of HTML5.

However, if there are any cache libraries, then it would be more efficient.

I know data.js, but it doesn't work with the error message: "no handler for data"

```
OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = true;        
OData.read("http://localhost/OData/OData.svc/GetDatasets", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I googled it with the error message so I modified the code like this.

```
var textHtmlHandler = {
    read: function (response, context) {
        var contentType = response.headers["Content-Type"];
        if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("text/html") === 0) {
            response.data = response.body;
        } else {
            odata.defaultHandler.read(response, context);
        }
    },
    write: function (request, context) { }
}

OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = true;
OData.read("http://localhost/OData/OData.svc/", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
function (err) {
    console.log(err);
},
textHtmlHandler);
```

Now it says: "ReferenceError"

I'm doubting that my data.js code because I don't need to use JSONP because it supports CORS.

```
$.ajax({            
    url: "http://cross-domain-address/OData/OData.svc?$format=json",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: a,
    error: b
});

function a(d) {
    console.log(d);
}

function b(d) {
    console.log(d);
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

You can suggest cache libraries for OData feed or correct the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consume OData feeds with J[ayData library](http://jaydata.org) and its OData provider - [OData cookbook with JayData](http://jaydata.org/blog/odata-cookbook-with-jaydata)
It is operating with datajs internally, but provides the same typed API to OData, WebSQL, SQLite and many other data sources - so you can store any results to in-browser dbs with the same syntax.

If you want to cache in the memory, you can try the [QueryCache module](http://jaystack.com/blog/query-cache-jaydata-pro-module) packaged with JayData Pro

Disclaimer: I'm member of JayData developer team, feel free to more info about the library or OData, hopefully I will be able to point you to the right blogpost.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information. I'll use the library for the next version's mobile website.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed one library for Client side caching the data. Here are the link

[Please Click here **jquery.cache-1.0.0**](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4BCpxHSHyZ9bXJsamo3UVVFMUU/edit?usp=sharing)